# I can't access phpmyadmin in wampserver

Tags: php, wamp, zend-optimizer

> I install zend-optimizer on wampserver, then I access link address
>   "localhost/phpmyadmin" is get error message

```
"Cannot load mysqli extension. Please check your PHP configuration. - Documentation"
```

> When I access folder "localhost/demo" is get error message `"Unable to connect to the database"`
>
> I using Wampserver (Php 5.2.8, Mysql 5.5.8 and Apache 2.2.17)

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli` is an extension, kind of like a driver, which PHP uses to communicate with MySQL.  It is one of a small handful of extensions PHPMyAdmin is able to connect to MySQL with.  You'll have to install the `mysqli` extension into your PHP setup or switch your PHPMyAdmin configuration to use a different driver.

[Here is an overview](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php) from the PHP manual describing how to install PHP extensions in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Never fear! Easy configuration is here! Click on PHP menu in Wamp tray icon. Then go to Extension submenu and scroll down the list to find php_mysqli. Click it (which will enable the extension) and then restart Wamp services.

Alternatively you can modify your PHP.ini. Look for the line `;extension=php_mysqli.dll` and remove the semi-colon. Then restart the Wamp services.

That should be it.